# What's the best way to 'include' a file in WordPress?

Tags: include

Ive built simple web applications in the past using 'include' functions and typically I've used this command:

```
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/data.php"); ?>
```

This has worked great OUTSIDE of WordPress but my question is - can this be applied to a WordPress Environment?

*(I should add the reason I am doing this: it is because I have to load a file which is approx 2MB into a WordPress Template and it crashes each time I try to save the file).*

Comment: using wordpress good practise is best like ` require_once ( get_template_directory() . "/data.php"); ` as @Jack Johansson is answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the PHP files in WordPress just the same way you do it anywhere else.

However, WordPress offers more constants and functions for defining a path for the `include()` function.

Instead of using `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, move your PHP file to your theme's folder, and use this to include it:

```
require_once ( get_template_directory() . "/data.php");
```

The reason behind moving the file to theme's folder is both for security, and  organization. Now, use this in the *very first line* of your `data.php` file:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) die();
```

This will prevent direct access to your PHP script by entering the URL. `ABSPATH` is a core WordPress constant, and if it's not defined, then it means your script is probably being accessed directly.

Also, to prevent accidental conflicts occurred by including the file multiple times, I would suggest you use `require_once()` instead.